# C++ source for testing memory checker tools?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, profiling, profiler

I'm currently doing research about memory checking tools for Windows 7, MS Visual Studio C++. For tools which are free, or have demo available, I would like to run special test: run a simple application which would contain as many different memory errors as possible so I could check how many of them the tool can detect.

So I would like to ask whether there is available source code in C++ for such application.

Notes:

- I Googled this thing, but all I could find are questions and sites about memory checking tools.
- Of course I could write such app (and I will do it if there is no such code available), but I know I will probably forget some kinds of errors. For example I even didn't think about checking whether memcpy's parameters are overlapping (which is an error - use memmove instead, or revise the code) until valgrind found it in my personal project (in this case, I copied an array into multiple places and I forgot (in a loop) to omit the first (source) array). I believe there is much more error types I never thought about.
- I cannot use valgrind as it MUST be Windows MS Visual C++ application, I cannot change this decision, and [valgrind under Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_and_Valgrind) looks like too complicated so I probably won't be able to convince my colleagues to use this solution. And it's not even sure that Wine will run our app...

Comment: regarding your third point: http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/DevelopmentEnvironment/

Comment: @stijn Thanks for the link, I didn't find it during my research. Problem is - I'm reading the page over and over again and I cannot find info whether this valgrind can profile applications compile with Mingw or whether application from MS Visual Studio are profiling-able, too. (This is also one of the things I cannot change - it must be MS VS.) In any case, thanks about the link, it's interesting for me anyway.

Comment: I actually don't know whether valgrind can use msvc compiled applications - you'll have to try it out I guess.,

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I'll check it when it'll be possible.